# source file corrupted while creating an rpm with rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating an rpm using rpmbuild.

The source file (a tar.gz) is correctly uncompressed in BUILDROOT/BUILD directories.

The rpm is created using :  `rpmbuild --clean -ba specfile`

While using that rpm the file extracted are not the same as the original one. The size of one of the files for example is 327 440 instead of 1 460 540.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. But I'll hazard a guess - if your file is an executable or shared object (`.so`) then it will be much smaller because all the [debug symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_Symbols) have been stripped out and moved into the `debuginfo` RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpmbuild` typically strips binaries, if it finds executable binaries under `%files`.

This is normal. It is a good thing, because it removes unnecessary debug symbols and, by default, extracts them to a `-debuginfo` package.

Nothing is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I used the following at the top of my spec file to disable the stripping :
`%global _enable_debug_package 0 
%global debug_package %{nil}
%global __os_install_post /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress %{nil}`